# graphicImage and streamed content primefaces and jsf

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

So, I have managed to upload images to my desired location and I gave name to these images same name of object property for example: fruit contains name apple and I have an apple.jpg.
I am able to see image directly when I call `<p:graphicImage name="apple.jpg" id="image" width="40" height="20" library="images" />`

Imagine that I have a datatable which contains all fruits and when i click on some fruit I want to get picture of that fruit.

```
if(item.getFruit().getLogo().getName() == item.getFruit().getName()){
   //show me image
}
```

I've searched whole stack and I've got lost.

Comment: Can you please write a specific question, maybe you want something like "How can I show the corresponding image of a selected row?". and try post a more complete code that describes better your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that:

- You have a folder with images
- Each image url is saved as String field into Fruit entity.

So, when you load a Fruit entity from database, you have a image full url.

```
<ui:repeat var="fruit" value="#{fruitBean.fruitListFromDatabase}">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{fruit.imageUrl}" rendered="#{!empty fruit.imageUrl}" />    
    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="no-image.png" rendered="#{empty fruit.imageUrl}" />  
</ui:repeat>
```

The previous code will render an image per Fruit, in case of no image uploaded (imageUrl is null), then a custom no-image.png is show.

`h:graphicImage` must use specifying library and name attributes when you have a image inside resources folder of your webapp.

Use `h:graphicImage` with value attribute, to show a full image URL.

Why we must not store uploaded images inside application resources file? Because on redeploy, the images will be lost.

To serve your custom folder, you can use some aproach that allows you create a virtual served directory, for example, if you are using Glassfish, in the glassfish-web.xml, you need to make a reference to external folder with the images:

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/media/* dir=/data" />
```

Now, the images can be found: "your-domain.com/media/some-image.png"

Comment: I removed the java tag you added since this problem is in no way java-se related (try reproducing with a plain jdk, no servlet container, no jsf, nothing... you won't succeed, hence not java-se related)